# Can't start a new game

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-black-white

I recently borrowed a copy of Pokemon White for Nintendo DS from a friend who bought it used, so there was already a complete game on it. I used <kbd>down</kbd> + <kbd>select</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to delete the game but whenever I try to play it it would say:

> The save data could not be accessed.
>   Please turn the power off and reinsert the game card.

I have tried doing this on my 3DS, as well as my old DS lite but when I attempt to play the game the same text will come up. I'm not very tech savvy so this might be some thing obvious and if so sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are pressing the wrong buttons, try instead: <kbd>up</kbd>+<kbd>select</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>